# How do I change my character model?

Tags: borderlands-2

Can I hack some game file to change game character models?

I wanted to play Borderlands 2 again. This time, I want to play as a Siren. But seriously, I don't like the 'Maya' model. Since we already have the 'Lilith' model in our game files, can we switch Maya's model with Lilith's, with some client side hacking?

Comment: Since you are playing as Maya, and its an FPS, you wont be seeing yourself much. Does what you look like really matter?

Comment: I use some 3rd person shooter mod.

Comment: Then I'd suggest looking for a "swap out models" or "additional models" mod.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen any mods with that capability.

But it stands to reason that with client-side hacking, anything is possible. 
Especially when you have all the files required.

So, in essence, unless you are willing to get your hands dirty and put in the work of hacking it yourself, there does not seem to be a way at the moment.